# Awk syntax for enclosing {}

Tags: awk, nawk

It is my understanding that in awk a conditional evaluation could be started using either of the following:

```
if ($0 ~ /no/) {cmd}
($0 ~ /no/) {cmd}
$0 ~ /no/ {cmd}
/no/ {cmd}
```

In the generic command line

```
BEGIN {  }  (body) END {  }
```

I find it most logical to enclose (body) in brackets, as in {(body} (referred to as "bracketed").

Under GNU awk, Ubuntu 12.04, only the 1st of the 4 options executes if bracketed - at least on my machine (the others produce syntax errors). If i run the line un-bracketed, only the 1st failed, the rest 3 work fine. Could someone carefully explain why that is so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) output from your code and all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear. Also, make sure to include some samples of what you're testing against.

Comment: Formatting has been corrected; as to examples: the question is clear as is: the "example" would be to rum it as usual (awk ' ' <filename>, receiving the nor very helpful "syntax error in line 1 near { syntax error in line 1 near }".

Comment: One clarification: I run it as 'awk', which I believe to be (from the man page) nawk, not awk proper.

Comment: do you mean `awk 'if ($0 ~ /no/) {cmd}' input` worked by you? it shouldn't though.

Comment: @Kent: You are right; it doesn't. I meant to edit question text reflecting this, but was not allowed to. Thanks much.

Comment: @gnometorule I edited the question for you, I hope it is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk statements follow the rule:

```
PATTERN{action}
```

So `BEGIN` or `END` are just special PATTERNs. basically if PATTERN is true, do the action in `{..}`

PATTERN could be regex, expression and range also **empty**.

the empty pattern looks like:

```
awk '{print "foo"}' input
```

You can read http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html section 7.1 for deatails.

Back to your question, if you executed those 4 lines in Action part, that is, between `{...}`, (in fact empty pattern), only the first, with `if` is valid conditional statement. However if you use the matching check as pattern, (outside the `{..}`):

```
if ($0 ~ /no/) {cmd} # this would ***NOT*** work, because it is statment, not valid awk expression. (I don't know how did you make it work.)

($0 ~ /no/) {cmd} # this will work, it is a boolean expression

$0 ~ /no/ {cmd} # same as above

/no/ {cmd} # this is regexp pattern, so it works too.
```

Comment: Very clear and logical; in particular did not know that BEGIN is a pattern (it makes sense to see it that way though). Thanks! :)

Comment: +1 Note that the "empty" pattern is **true** for every record.

Answer (score 3):

Syntactically, an awk script is a set of rules, like the following [[Ref]](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getting-Started):

```
pattern { action }
pattern { action }
....
```

Where `pattern` is an expression, and `action` is a series of commands that are executed if `pattern` is evaluated to true (a non-zero number, or a non-empty string).

If the `pattern` is omitted, then `action` will be executed for every record.

If the `{ action }` part is omitted, the default action is executed, which is `{ print $0 }` or `{ print }` (equivalent).

As you mentioned in the question, `pattern` can be `BEGIN`, `END`, ... etc, or any other expression.

Your first example will be executed correctly in the `{ action }` block, since it is a command. The other three options are not commands, but are combinations of `pattern { action }` blocks.

Comment: +1 A non-empty string is also a true value http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Truth-Values.html#Truth-Values